# Mapping text to HTML entity in Doxygen

Tags: c++, documentation, comments, doxygen

In Doxygen, to get the copyright symbol in HTML output, the documentation must use `&copy;`, as in:

```
/// @copyright Copyright &copy; 2012
```

In this case, I'd prefer to type it like this:

```
/// @copyright Copyright (c) 2012
```

In the latter example, it looks a little nicer and would probably translate over to plain text & RTF output better as well. Is it possible to create a text to entity mapping in Doxygen? For example, `(c)` would map to `&copy;`, and doxygen would simply replace all `(c)` occurrences with `&copy;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general I think such substitutions are better handled by an input filter.
Here is a simple filter that would replace a `(c)` followed by some digits by `&copy;` and then the same digits:

```
#!/bin/perl
open(F,"<$ARGV[0]") || die("Failed to open file $ARGV[0]: $!");
while (<F>)
{
  s/\([cC]\)(\s*\d+)/&copy;\1/g;
  print $_;
}
close(F);
```

To use this filter put the following in the config file:

```
INPUT_FILTER = "perl filter.pl"
```

**Note 1** The filter will process the whole file. It might be a useful feature to allow a filter that is only applied to comments.

**Note 2** If you use a UTF-8 capable editor and corresponding encoding (INPUT_ENCODING) you can also insert the copyright character directly (code C2 A9 hex)